# Establishing Page Titles for items categorized as (Not Set) within analytics only

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a way within analytics to have a specific page title display in place of (not set)?

I have several different items categorized as the page title (not set).. For example can I get randomlink/index to automatically assign to the page title "Landing Page" rather than (not set) within analytics?

Can this be done through content grouping or other methods?

Answer (score 0):

The data already collected in Google Analytics can not be changed.

You can assign a value, in each page on the website that doesn't have a title, for future hits by providing a custom 'title' using the `ga('set'` script

eg:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
(...)
if (!document.title) {
  ga('set', 'title', 'my custom title');
}
(...)
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Make sure this code runs **before** a pageview is sent.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#title